# Finding $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\space\Big (\frac {π(2n+1)}{π(2n)}\Big)^n $

Tags: limits, prime-numbers

Let  $ \pi(x)$ denote the prime counting function.Then what is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}sup\space\Big (\frac {π(2n+1)}{π(2n)}\Big)^n $   ?

Comment: For every odd integer $n$, $\pi(n+1)=\pi(n)$. This rules out the limit you propose.

Comment: Even after the correction, for most even numbers $2n$, $\pi(2n) = \pi(2n+1)$. Would $\limsup$ be applicable, perhaps?

Comment: @Arthur: Is it okay now ?

Comment: But didn't Charles post a computation of the limsup several hours ago?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oh , right , I did not notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\pi(x)$ is unbounded above, and $\pi(2n+1)=\pi(2n)$ except on a subsequence of density 0. So
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}n\log\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{\pi(2n)}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}n\log1=0.
$$

On the other side it suffices to look at the subsequence of primes:
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}n\log\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{\pi(2n)}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{2}\log\frac{n+1}{n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=+\infty
$$